# How does recursion access nested lists?

Tags: python, recursion

```
def count_even(obj):
"""
Return the number of even numbers in obj or sublists of obj
if obj is a list.  Otherwise, if obj is a number, return 1
if it is an even number and 0 if it is an odd number.

@param int|list obj: object to count even numbers from
@rtype: int

>>> count_even(3)
0
>>> count_even(16)
1
>>> count_even([1, 2, [3, 4], 5])
2
"""
count = 0
if isinstance(obj, int):
    if obj % 2 == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
else:
    for i in obj:
        count += count_even(i)
    return new
```

I don't understand how in the 2nd-last line "count+= count_even(i)", "recursion" is able to access, for example, the nested list [3,4] from [1,2,[3,4],5].

Wouldn't the for loop go through each item { i=0 (1), i=1 (2), i=2 ([3,4]), i=3 (5) }, looking for an int, and not have the if statement trigger for [3,4], since it's a list?

Comment: Is the last line of the code correct? I'd expect `return count`, rather than `return new` (which should raise an exception since `new` is not defined).

Answer (score 3):

The function is able to access the nested list `[3, 4]` because, as you stated, the value `[3, 4]` skips over the first  `if` (because `[3, 4]` is not an `int`) **and so then executes the else**.  In the else, you will get another loop over `[3, 4]` which will then check `3` and `4` for odd/evenness.

here’s a trace to help you sort things out:

```
obj = [ 1, 2, [3, 4], 5 ]
count_even(obj) =>
  count_even([ 1, 2, [3, 4], 5]) =>
    is obj an `int`?  No =>
      for i in [ 1, 2, [3, 4], 5] =>
        count_even(1) =>
           is 1 an int?  Yes => return 0 because 1 is odd
        count_even(2)
           is 2 an int?  Yes => return 1 because 2 is even
        count_even([3, 4]) =>
           is [3, 4] an int?  No =>
             for i in [3, 4] =>
               count_even(3) =>
                 Is 3 an int?  Yes => return 0 because 3 is odd
               count_even(4) =>
                 Is 4 and int?  Yes => return 1 because 4 is even
        count_even(5) =>
           is 5 an int?  Yes => return 0 because 5 is odd
```